# Groupby sum and average in pandas and make data frame

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
ID     Score
A      20
B      60
A      40
C      50
B      100
C      60
C      40
A      10
A      10
A      70
```

From the above I would like to calculate the average score for each ID and total score.

Expected output:

```
ID    Average_score     Total_score
A     30                150
B     80                160
C     50                150
```

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').agg(['mean','sum'])`

Comment: see answer @cs95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named aggregation for custom columns names:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID').agg(Average_score=('Score','mean'), 
                            Total_score=('Score','sum'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  ID  Average_score  Total_score
0  A             30          150
1  B             80          160
2  C             50          150
```